# Include same js file in multiple html.erb files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is a javascript file that is included in one `html.erb` persistent even in the other view with a different url? For eg: Suppose the flow is if I click on `Go` button in `new` then the user is directed to `show` page and I include js file only in `new.html.erb` then is the js file also available in `show`?

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'common' %>
```

So are the functions in `common.js` file available in `my_domain/show` just like how it is available in `my_domain/new`? Or should I include the js file again in `show.html.erb`?

Also I would like to know the best way to include same javacript file in partials. For eg as below:

**main.html.erb**

```
<% if some_condition %>
  <% render partial: 'first_partial' %>
<% elsif some_other_condition %>
  <% render partial: 'second_partial' %>
<% else %>
  <% render partial: 'first_partial' %>
  <% render partial: 'second_partial' %>
<% end %>
```

**_first_partial.html.erb**

```
#some code
<%= javascript_include_tag 'common' %>
```

**_second_partial.html.erb**

```
#some code
<%= javascript_include_tag 'common' %>
```

Here in the `main` for `if` and `elsif` condition I render only one of the partials so I can include the js file in any partial but for the third `else` condition since both the partials are rendered, what is the best way to include the js file? and also I cannot include the js file in `main` because the js file is called after the html in the partials is rendered.

Comment: I edited my answer - why do you think you cannot load it in the main file?

Comment: The `main` file has other code also. I have only pasted the necessary content for this question. The `if` conditions in the question are inside another `if` block. So the js file is unnecessary when the other condition is not satisfied in main file. So I do not include it and also the js only has functions on the html elements in those partials.

Comment: Basically what I wanted to ask was if two partials in the same parent html.erb file or a partial inside a partial of the parent html.erb require the same js file then what is the best way to include the js file. My question is not completely clear I guess.

Comment: I get the question :)  And the answer is, you can put it in the main file, even if that seems a bit weird. But always remember, the partials will just be all merged into a big html file. I will update my answer

Comment: @Clara I have opened another question where I have asked the doubt more clearly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938008/include-js-file-in-nested-partials-in-html-erb-in-rails Please go through this question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, normally the javascript code is not available in the other views, just in the one where you include it. So you need to include it again.

The exception would be if you have it in a layout file like `application.html.erb` because this on is rendered in all views.

If you call the javascript package in both partials anyway, then you can also just call it in main, after the if statement. This will be loaded after the partials have been loaded. It might seem weird, to require a piece javascript in a file that doesn't seem to have the html elements that you are using in the JS file, however, the partials are just a way to organise the code in rails. In the end they will be merged into one big html file.

In the comments you said this if statement is nested into another if statement, so maybe you don't need the javascript at all? Paste it at the end of the if statement like so

```
<% if outer_if_statment %>
  <% if some_condition %>
    <% render partial: 'first_partial' %>
  <% elsif some_other_condition %>
    <% render partial: 'second_partial' %>
  <% else %>
    <% render partial: 'first_partial' %>
    <% render partial: 'second_partial' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'common' %>
<% else %>
...
<% end %>
```

This way it will be available in for all partials but not, if the inner if statement is not chosen.

Another thing:
Javascript should be loaded at the end of the html file anyway so that the user doens't have to wait for it to load while he/she doesn't see any html elements. If we put the javascript right in the middle of a hmtl file like this, we're infringing this principle.

Now there is a helper to that:
You can define a second `yield` in your `application.html.erb`

```
 <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>

    <%= yield(:after_js) %>
</body>
```

In the views, you can call it like this:

```
<%= content_for :after_js do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'common' %>
<% end %>
```

This will make sure, that the JS is loaded at the end of the body and that all other JS code is loaded beforehand (if there are any dependencies).
And, if you still only want to load it depending on the conditions you could repeat the if statement inside the `content_for` block.

Depending on what your JS script looks like, you can also make sure it only executes, if the necessary HTML element is found on the page. Let's imagine you want to add an event listener on a button.

```
// common.js
const button = document.querySelector("#red-button")
if (button) {
  button.addEventListener(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question. Please go through the question. Your answer is correct for the previous version of my question but my edit got uploaded late. So you had already answered for the previous version.